# how to change the value of fields in a module through views ..

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have already done it by using logic hooks how can i do it through views.I have already done it through logic hooks but how can i acheive it through using views only and that too through code

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for just setting the default value in a view? Saving a value can only be done after the fact using a hook. If you want to do something like set a default value in the edit (or detail view) just set the field in $this->bean:

```
class AccountsViewDetail extends ViewDetail {
    function display(){
        $this->bean->mycustomfield_c = 'Default';   
......
```